# Does ELMAH provide any methods to READ the errors from the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, elmah, elmah.mvc

I am working with ASP.Net C# application and using ELMAH to log errors to SQL database. 
I need to retrieve the errors from the database, does ELMAH provide any methods to search an error (and return something such as JSON)? Or does ELMAH only logs the errors, and reading part has to be donelike any other database read?

I have checked online and at https://elmah.github.io/ . I could not find any lead to the solution of this issue.

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ELMAH provides a simple UI for browsing errors, available on the URL `/elmah.axd` (or `/elmah` if you are using the [elmah.mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/) NuGet package). Searching isn't supported, but you can export errors from the UI.